# Use Reflection to get PropertyInfo, only want to see accessors that have mutators

Tags: c#, system.reflection

Using reflection I want to retrieve only the properties that have both a `get` and a `set` method, and ignore ones with only a `get`. What I'm trying to do is give the user a list of variables that he/she is able to change, so showing them properties that only have a `get` method is misleading.

Given this code below, the user would only be shown `Name`. Or I could possibly show them both, but grey-out `UniqueID` so they know they cannot change it.

```
public Int64 UniqueID
{
    get { return this.uniqueID; }
}

public String Name
{
    get { return this.name; }
    set { this.name = value; }
}
```

Background Info: I'm using C# 4.0.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `CanRead` and `CanWrite` properties:

```
Type type = ...
var readWriteProps = type.GetProperties()
                         .Where(p => p.CanRead && p.CanWrite);
```

Do note that the above query looks only for public properties with public accessors.

Comment: This works great, thanks. I'd up-vote you, but I don't have enough rep to do so.

Answer (score 3):

I think the property you are looking for is `PropertyInfo.CanWrite` and this can be implemented as the following to check both Get and Set with something like:

```
if (propInfo.CanWrite && propInfo.CanRead)
```